# Ruby on Rails: how to use find on multiple conditions and multiple tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a product model and a category model. Product has_many_and_belongs_to Category, and vice-versa. Now I want to use Product.find to search for a Product.name but also a Product.categories. I tried something like this but it didn't work:

```
Product.find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ? or categories LIKE ?', '%#{keyword}%']
```

Basically, I'm trying to get results for products with name like 'car' or products with a category of 'car'. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

```
Product.joins(:categories).where('products.name LIKE ? or categories.name LIKE ?', "%#{keyword}")
```

I think something like this can help you if you using rails > 3